How can I sort a set of data according to their first line in python?
I have a set of data that need to be sorted based on their time. The data is:
 2006  1 3 1501 12.0 L  28.024  56.808 14.1  INS  3 0.0 3.9LINS                1
 GAP=158        0.32       2.7     8.0 13.4 -0.2096E+02 -0.1022E+03  0.3316E+02E
 ACTION:UPD 06-08-20 20:40 OP:moh  STATUS:               ID:20060103150113 L   I
 2006-01-03-1500-10S.NSN___036                                                 6
 STAT SP IPHASW D HRMM SECON CODA AMPLIT PERI AZIMU VELO AIN AR TRES W  DIS CAZ7
 BNDS BZ EPG      15 1 27.99                              90     0.010 93.4 222 
 BNDS BN ESG      15 1 39.77                              90     0.010 93.4 222 
 BNDS BE  AML     15 1 43.17      1880.4 0.39                          93.4 222 
 BNDS BN  AML     15 1 48.04      2173.7 0.56                          93.4 222 
 KRBR BZ EPG      15 1 47.76                              90     0.010  217 359 
 KRBR BN ESG      15 2 13.87                              90     0.010  217 359 
 KRBR BE  AML     15 2 17.46      2411.2 0.45                           217 359 
 KRBR BN  AML     15 2 17.52      2481.1 0.64                           217 359 
 ZHSF BZ EPN      15 2 12.69                              52     0.0 9  425  65 

 2005  110 1521 29.5 L  26.988  55.807 14.1  INS  3 0.1 3.2LINS                1
 GAP=260        0.41       6.4     1.9  5.5 -0.7704E+01 -0.3485E+01  0.2469E+02E
 ACTION:UPD 06-08-20 20:40 OP:moh  STATUS:               ID:20060110151405 L   I
 2006-01-10-1514-05S.NSN___039                                                 6
 STAT SP IPHASW D HRMM SECON CODA AMPLIT PERI AZIMU VELO AIN AR TRES W  DIS CAZ7
 BNDS BZ EPG      1521 39.93                              90     0.010 58.1  38 
 BNDS BE ESG      1521 47.41                              90    -0.110 58.1  38 
 BNDS BE  AML     1522 16.19      1554.5 0.64                          58.1  38 
 BNDS BN  AML     1522 17.86      1657.6 0.60                          58.1  38 
 GHIR BZ EPN      1522 16.05                              52    -0.110  313 298 
 GHIR BN ESG      1522 57.55                              90     0.010  313 298 
 KRBR BZ EPN      1522 20.37                              52     0.1 9  345  15 
 KRBR BE  AML     1523 16.05        72.3 0.64                           345  15 
 KRBR BN  AML     1523 27.24        63.0 0.52                           345  15 

As instance, you can see two elements of such big data set. The data was separated by backspace and I am going to sort them by time (first line of each element is "year", "month", "day", "hour", "min", and etc. For read the data in python, the following can be used:
What I expected:
 2005  110 1521 29.5 L  26.988  55.807 14.1  INS  3 0.1 3.2LINS                1
 GAP=260        0.41       6.4     1.9  5.5 -0.7704E+01 -0.3485E+01  0.2469E+02E
 ACTION:UPD 06-08-20 20:40 OP:moh  STATUS:               ID:20060110151405 L   I
 2006-01-10-1514-05S.NSN___039                                                 6
 STAT SP IPHASW D HRMM SECON CODA AMPLIT PERI AZIMU VELO AIN AR TRES W  DIS CAZ7
 BNDS BZ EPG      1521 39.93                              90     0.010 58.1  38 
 BNDS BE ESG      1521 47.41                              90    -0.110 58.1  38 
 BNDS BE  AML     1522 16.19      1554.5 0.64                          58.1  38 
 BNDS BN  AML     1522 17.86      1657.6 0.60                          58.1  38 
 GHIR BZ EPN      1522 16.05                              52    -0.110  313 298 
 GHIR BN ESG      1522 57.55                              90     0.010  313 298 
 KRBR BZ EPN      1522 20.37                              52     0.1 9  345  15 
 KRBR BE  AML     1523 16.05        72.3 0.64                           345  15 
 KRBR BN  AML     1523 27.24        63.0 0.52                           345  15
 
 2006  1 3 1501 12.0 L  28.024  56.808 14.1  INS  3 0.0 3.9LINS                1
 GAP=158        0.32       2.7     8.0 13.4 -0.2096E+02 -0.1022E+03  0.3316E+02E
 ACTION:UPD 06-08-20 20:40 OP:moh  STATUS:               ID:20060103150113 L   I
 2006-01-03-1500-10S.NSN___036                                                 6
 STAT SP IPHASW D HRMM SECON CODA AMPLIT PERI AZIMU VELO AIN AR TRES W  DIS CAZ7
 BNDS BZ EPG      15 1 27.99                              90     0.010 93.4 222 
 BNDS BN ESG      15 1 39.77                              90     0.010 93.4 222 
 BNDS BE  AML     15 1 43.17      1880.4 0.39                          93.4 222 
 BNDS BN  AML     15 1 48.04      2173.7 0.56                          93.4 222 
 KRBR BZ EPG      15 1 47.76                              90     0.010  217 359 
 KRBR BN ESG      15 2 13.87                              90     0.010  217 359 
 KRBR BE  AML     15 2 17.46      2411.2 0.45                           217 359 
 KRBR BN  AML     15 2 17.52      2481.1 0.64                           217 359 
 ZHSF BZ EPN      15 2 12.69                              52     0.0 9  425  65 


Split the  text into list of strings, then use sorted with custom key function

How is 2005  110 1521 ... year month day ...??

2005 is year, 1 is month, 10 is day, 15 is hour and 21 is minute (left to right)

If the file fits into memory you can split it into blocks (separated by double \n) and sort them with the built-in sorted function using a custom key
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines = sorted(f.read().split("\n\n"))

print("\n~~~\n".join(lines)) # verify

EDIT: according to the comment each block in the file starts with a 14-characters date string in the format %Y %m%d %hh%mm with no space between month and day and space-padding instead of zero-padding. For instance 2006  1 3 1501  is YYYY MMDD HHMM.
Here's the modified code with sort by custom key:
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    lines =f.read().split("\n\n")
# sort by first 14 characters in block
lines = sorted(lines, key=lambda x: x[:14])
print("\n~~~\n".join(lines))

